# Params in url by htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using below code:

```
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)sort_field=more&limit=&p=(&|$) [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?sort_field=more&limit=&p= [L,R=301,QSA]
```

But it add params on all pages. I need add params only to main domain. How can I do it?

Comment: Please add more details here to help us understand. What do you refer to by "main domain", "pages"? Where is your condition limiting the rule to only a specific URL being requested?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, these directives don't apply, because they have a hash `#` in front of them.

---

The query string (params) is added to all pages, because the pattern `^` (beginning of URL) matches all pages. If you want to match only a specific page, you must use an appropriate pattern, see [Regular Expressions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex) for details how to specify a pattern.

In your case, main domain (main page?), it would be just `^$` or `^index.html$` or similar, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^$ %{REQUEST_URI}?sort_field=more&limit=&p= [L,R,QSA]
```

---

When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301`. *Never* test with [`R=301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).